# How to send a wakeup signal to a child from parent c++

Tags: c++, linux

```
int main()
{

    pid_t pid=fork();

    if(pid>0)
    {
        int a;
        cout<<"do you want to wake up the child? 1=yes/0=no "<<endl;
        cin>>a;
        if(a==1)
        {

            kill(pid,SIGUSR2);
            int status;
            waitpid(pid,&status,0);


        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"i didn't wake up the child"<<endl;

        }
        exit(0);
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        pause();

        cout<<"i'm starting working"<<endl;
        int n=0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            n+=4;
            cout<<n<<endl;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

i am using these libraries:
seems like that the pause() in the child is not getting any signal from the parents , and the child does not do the output.
where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing at least one `#include` and/or some function prototypes. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

From `pause` manual page:

> pause() causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the
>   invocation of a signal-catching function.

Since you do not have any handlers installed for SIGUSR2, the signal terminates the process and you see no output.